# Tab Bar Controller Fully Grey with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

[image]

I recently made a Single View app. I have a login and sign up screen working w/ Firebase. However, everything was working until I decided to create a **Tab Bar Controller** into the user interface. It doesn't work due to this **allover** **grey** color! I absolutely can't remove it... Does anyone of you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Assign pictures to each of the uitabbar controller elements. Does it take them away?

Comment: It's finally working! Thank's